# How do I get the fully-qualified object name in a BIRT report?

Tags: uml, birt, rational-rsa

I have a BIRT report in Rational Software Architect that outputs an element's name in one column. When I run the report on my whole project, I get lots of duplicate columns because I have elements with the same (unqualified) name in different packages. How can I edit the BIRT report to use the fully-qualified name?

Comment: How are you accessing the element's name?  What is the source of the information?

Answer (score 0):

The standard UML data sets do not have this element value we must add it from the modeling data source to the data sets you want.

In the data sets which you are reading for you report table, right click 
the "data set"->edit.  Select Column Mapping from the list in the Edit Data Set window that popped up.  In the Browse grouping select the model dropdown button and select the uml meta-element in question.  Expand the tree until you get to a list of properties/attributes and select the qualifiedName, click the > button to add the attribute it will add a column with the query @qualifiedName.  Finish and enjoy.

NOTE: Some UML meta-element types do not have this attribute, if you can't refine your data set to one that does I saw this hack... adding a column called path with a query of ../@qualifiedName which got the path or parent qualifiedName as it will more than likely have one (Component, Package, etc).  It worked for the Element type.